# what's result for sql server log backup twice?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a sql server database mydb. Then I run a transaction log backup at 12:00pm.
Then run the transaction log backup(either full or differential) again at 12:30pm.

what's result for the second backup? any possible problem for this case?

Comment: Oh gosh, there is so much external reading you could do before you're at the point you're worried about specific problems...

Answer (score 1):

When you run a log backup, you don't specify full or differential, you just backup the log.

Log backups back up transactions that have taken place since the last log backup, or if a log backup doesn't exist, since the last database backup.

Recovery Point and Recovery Time objectives will direct how often you want to take log backups.

If, for instance, you do a full backup on Monday morning, then do log backups every 5 minutes, you could restore to Monday at 1:45pm by restoring the full backup and every log backup that has taken place up to 1:45pm.

Answer (score 1):

You are not completely understanding the concepts.

Over simplifying the concepts:

**FULL BACKUP** : It will contain all the data + enough log to allow the database to be recovered to a consistent state.

**Differential Backup** : Contains all the data since the last full backup.

**Log Backup** : In full recovery model (you cant take a log backup in simple recovery mode), it will contain the backup of transaction logs that includes all log records that were not backed up in a previous log backup.

**Lets take your questions one by one :**

> If I have a sql server database mydb. Then I run a transaction log backup at 12:00pm.

Assuming that your database is in full recovery mode (which it should be as in simple recovery mode you cannot take a T-log backup), if you have not taken a full backup, then your database would be in [PSEUDO recovery mode](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/new-script-is-that-database-really-in-the-full-recovery-mode/).

You must take a full backup to establish the log chain.

Now assuming above, you take a log backup at 12:00 PM which is fine.

> Then run the transaction log backup(either full or differential) again at 12:30pm.
>
> what's result for the second backup? any possible problem for this case?

IF you take a T-log backup at 12:30, it should be fine and you will end up with 2 log backups and you will be able to do a [point-in-time recovery](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1229/sql-server-point-in-time-recovery/) of your database.

If you do a full backup, that is fine as well - as it wont break the log chain.

If you do a differential backup, then when doing a database restore, you have to

restore latest full backup, then restore the latest differential backup and then the subsequent log backups to bring the database to a point in time.

Refer to **[this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55418/missing-transaction-log-in-chain-possible-to-skip/55445#55445)** as I have explained it in more details.

References :

- [Backup Overview (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-overview-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [TRANSACTION LOG BACKUP and RESTORE SEQUENCE: Myths & Truths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverfaq/transaction-log-backup-and-restore-sequence-myths-truths)