# Which Log should I start backups with?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

We have log backups running every 15 minutes and nightly fulls/diffs (fulls are once a week per DB, but they are spread across the whole week for load balancing). Lets say for a particular DB I have a diff that starts at 10:05pm and finishes at 10:18pm and I have log backups at 10:00pm, 10:15pm, and 10:30pm. If I want to restore to 10:24pm that night, I know I need to restore the last full and the diff from that night, but then I'm not sure which transaction log I should start with after that.

Comment: Check [**this**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102203/8783) answer for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to restore last `FULL` backup, the `Differential`, the 10:15 `transaction` backup and the 10:30 one with the `STOPAT = '2015-05-22 22:24:00'` clause.

Answer (score 2):

First thing if transaction log is not damaged you should go for [tail log backup](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-backing-up-the-tail-of-the-log/). That would cause minimal data loss. Then restore would be

1. Weekly full backup with no recovery
2. 10:05PM Differential backup with no recovery
3. All log backups after this differential backup with no recovery and finally tail log backup with stopat command with recovery

Please read about [stopat command](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/debunking-a-couple-of-myths-around-full-database-backups/)

Make sure you don't forget to test backup validity before restoring just in case.